# Escape again after value manipulation in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, sql-injection, mysql-real-escape-string

Let's say i have this code:

```
$value = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['value']);
$value = strip_tags($value, '<br>');
```

for example with this value: `$_POST['value'] = "<div>how<br/> you doin'?</div>";`.

Should I escape `$value` after changing its text value? It contains an apostrophe that can cause problems with the mysqli queries, or even a SQL Injection. Thanks!

Comment: No. Your script would be at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even
[if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)